# Import Error while making a package using setup.py

Tags: python, package, importerror, setup.py, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to build a python package which has a setup.py file , I created an entry point but I run through it then it gives import error otherwise if run normally in vs code it does not gives import error ,

```
C:.
│   setup.py
│
├───build
│   ├───bdist.win-amd64
│   └───lib
│       └───treasure_hunt
│               death.py

│               energy.py
│               map.py
│               path_scenes.py
│               scenes.py
│               setup.py
│               treasurehunt.py
│               __init__.py
│
├───treasure_hunt
│   │   death.py
│   │   energy.py
│   │   map.py
│   │   path_scenes.py
│   │   scenes.py
│   │   setup.py
│   │   treasurehunt.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───treasure_hunt.egg-info
│   │       dependency_links.txt
│   │       entry_points.txt
│   │       PKG-INFO
│   │       SOURCES.txt
│   │       top_level.txt
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           death.cpython-310.pyc
│           energy.cpython-310.pyc
│           energy.cpython-312.pyc
│           map.cpython-310.pyc
│           path_scenes.cpython-310.pyc
│           scenes.cpython-310.pyc
│           treasurehunt.cpython-312.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-312.pyc
│
└───treasure_hunt.egg-info
        dependency_links.txt
        entry_points.txt
        PKG-INFO
        SOURCES.txt
        top_level.txt
```

this is my setup.py file-
try :
from setuptools import setup
except:
from distutils.tools import setup

```
config = {
"packages":["treasure_hunt"],
"entry_points":{
    "console_scripts":"play=treasurehunt:main"
}
}

setup(**config)
```

this is the treasurehunt.py file which contains the main() function-

```
def main():
    from .energy import Energy
    from .scenes import *
    from .path_scenes import *

    scene_map = {
        "scene1":scenes.Scene1(),
        "scene2":scenes.Scene2(),
        "scene3":scenes.Scene3(),
        "scene4":scenes.Scene4(),
        "scene5":scenes.Scene5(),
        "scene6":scenes.Scene6(),
    }

    path_scene_map = {
        "scene1":path_scenes.Pathscene4(),
        "scene3":path_scenes.Pathscene1(),
        "scene2":path_scenes.Pathscene5(),
        "scene5":path_scenes.Pathscene3(),
        "scene4":path_scenes.Pathscene6(),
        "scene6":path_scenes.Pathscene2(),
    }



    name = "scene1"
    x = Energy()
    while True:
        energylevel = x.show()
        x.warning()
        path_scene_map[name].path()
        energylevel = energylevel-1
        name = scene_map[name].enter()
        energylevel = energylevel-1
```

when i run the play command it shows module not found error

Comment: `play=treasurehunt:main` you have no module named `treasurehunt` should be `play=treasure_hunt:main`

Comment: What about: `play=treasure_hunt.treaserhunt:main` ?

Comment: i have tried both of them but it does not work , it says no module named scenes and similar errors